# Navbar having different functionality based on page

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular application where I have my main app component housing a navbar that links to other components with the `routerLink` directive. Very simplified, it looks like this:

```
<nav>
    <button [routerLink]="['/foo']>
        Foo
    </button>
    <button id="button_to_change" [routerLink]="['/bar']>
        Button whose functionality I'd like to change
    </button>
</nav>
<div [@routeAnimation]='prepRouteState(routerOutlet)'>
    <router-outlet #routerOutlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

In one component (say the `foo` component that would be navigated to in the above example), I'd like to change the functionality of the second button `bar` just for that component. Is there any way I can do this programatically in the typescript component code? For example, for that component, can I change where `bar` routes to?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use  `(click)="barClicked()"` instead of `[routerLink]="['/bar']` for dynamic operation

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe router event to check which component is loaded then put your logic for hide show each button.

In your navbar component

```
class Navbar {
  showButton:boolean=false;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((val) => {
        console.log(val instanceof NavigationEnd)
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          if(event.url === "yourcomponentroute"){
             this.showButton=true
          }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Navbar html can be like

```
<nav>
    <button [routerLink]="['/foo']>
        Foo
    </button>
    <button *ngIf="!showButton" id="button_to_change" [routerLink]="['/bar']>
        Button for other components
    </button>
    <button *ngIf="showButton" id="button_to_change" [routerLink]="['/bar']>
        Button for foo component
    </button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using *ngIf + getter and a service to store the page

Your service

```
@Injectable()
export class NavService {
    pagina:string
}
```

Your nav.component

```
<nav>
    <button [routerLink]="['/foo']>
        Foo
    </button>
    <button *ngIf="pagina=='uno' [routerLink]="['/uno']>
        Uno
    </button>
    <button *ngIf="pagina=='dos' [routerLink]="['/dos']>
        Dos
    </button>
</nav>

export class NavComponent {
   get pagina()
   {
       return this.navService.pagina
   }
   constructor(private navService:NavService){}
}
```

Your component

```
export class UnoComponent implements onInit {
   set pagina(value)
   {
        this.navService.pagina=value;
   }
   constructor(private navService:NavService){}
   ngOnInit(){
       pagina="uno";
   }
}
```